# SpellCheck suggestion didn't populate the expect result

Tags: solr, spell-checking

All. Forgive me I am a newbie in Solr, I am trying to add spell check in the Solr.

Currently I can say it works .But I got a problem which the suggestion is not showing up as I expected.

I tried to search with the keywords `lu`. and expect the suggestion `lung` in the result. But it doesn't show up.

the Url is `http://10.2.21.38:7574/solr/gettingstarted_shard1_replica2/spell?q=lu&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.collate=true&spellcheck.build=true`

Only when I tried with `lun`. It can return suggestion `lung`.

[image]

Any idea to get it work? Thanks.

**Updated**

It seems it has something with the configuration `<str name="accuracy">{number}</str>` the original value is 0.7. When I changed it to smaller value like 0.001 . keywords `lu` can get the suggestion `lung`.

But I want to know what does it mean for the `accuracy`. The document only say a little about it .`The accuracy setting defines the threshold for a valid
suggestion`. That is it.

Could someone please tell me more about it for better understanding . and Is there any other configuration to affect the suggestion result ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The accuracy setting refers to the value that the active StringDistance calculator returns (which is between 0 and 1, depending on similarity). The standard distance measurer in Lucene is the [LevensteinDistance](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-suggest/5.2.1/org/apache/lucene/search/spell/LevensteinDistance.java#LevensteinDistance) (sic). I'll refer to the source to see how it works - I'm not intimately familiar with the code. The returned value is at least based on:

```
return 1.0f - ((float) p[n] / Math.max(other.length(), sa.length));
```

Where p[n] is calculated through the iteration above in the code.

You can change most implementations in the spellchecker, such as the distance measurer or the spellchecker itself. See [Spell Checking](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spell+Checking) for examples. `maxEdits` and `minPrefix` might be interesting as well. Also, remember that *lu* and *lung* have a fairly large difference, as both terms are short and not really misspellings of each other. There are other ways of doing automagic completion, such as the Suggest module or wild card searching against a StrField or a KeywordTokenizer-ed field.

Comment: +1 Thanks your help.  It is really give me more information to do auto completion. I didn't know the Suggest also can do it . Thanks.